# trues and length of bool list f#

Tags: f#

Directly using recursion, write a function `truesAndLength : bool list -> int * int` that
returns both the length of the list (in the first component of the pair), and the number of
elements of the list that are true (in the second component). Your function must only iterate
over the elements of the list once. (Do not use any of the functions from the List module.)

this is my code so far:

```
let rec length bs =
    match bs with
    | [] -> 0
    | b::bs -> 1 + length bs

let rec trues bs = 
    match bs with
    | [] -> 0
    | b::bs -> if b = true then 1 + trues bs else trues bs

let truesandlength bs =
    let l = length bs
    let t = trues bs
    (l, t)

truesandlength [true; true; false]
```

This works by im iterating through the list 2 times, i can't figure out how to iterate only 1. Any tips?

Comment: This looks like a homework question. You're on the right track. Just combine the `length` and `trues` functions into a single function that follows the same pattern matching approach.

Comment: yeah I've been trying to do that but i can't figure out how i return this type: bool list -> int * int, because i get an error when i try this e.g.  | [] -> 0,0 or | [] -> (0,0)

Comment: `| [] -> 0,0` is correct (and so is `(0,0)`), so I think the error must be elsewhere. What do you have for the `| b::bs ->` branch?

Comment: oh okay thanks, "  | b::bs -> 1 + truesAndLength, if b = true then 1 + truesAndLength bs else truesAndLength bs " i know this is maybe far from correct but this is what i have so far

Comment: See my suggestion in the answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on your comments, here's how I suggest you think about the `b::bs` case:

- Call `truesAndLengths` recursively on the tail of the list. This gives you `tTail` (the # of trues) and `lTail` (the length) of the tail.
- Compute `t` and `l` for the full list based on the value of `b`. (E.g. `l` is one more than `lTail`.)
- Return `t, l`.

The key is to call `truesAndLengths` recursively in only one place in your code, passing it the tail of the list.

Comment: okay thanks ! this is what i came up with but get an error `| b::bs -> let lLength = 1 + truesandlength2 bs
               let tTrues = if b = true then 1 + truesandlength2 bs else truesandlength2 bs
               lLength, tTrues`

Comment: i figured it out :)

Comment: `let rec truesAndLength bs = 
  let sum a b = (fst a + fst b, snd a + snd b)
  match bs with
  | [] -> 0, 0
  | head::tail ->
    if head then sum (1,1) (truesAndLength tail) else sum (1, 0) (truesAndLength tail)`

Answer (score 2):

```
let rec truesAndLength bs = 
  let sum a b = (fst a + fst b, snd a + snd b)
  match bs with
  | [] -> 0, 0
  | head::tail ->
    if head then sum (1,1) (truesAndLength tail) else sum (1, 0) (truesAndLength tail)
```

Comment: This way, you still traverse the list multiple times, as you call `truesAndLength` two times. Do the call before the `if`. `let length,trues = truesAndLength tail; if head = true then ....`

Comment: Actually, I think what OP has here works fine. Only one branch of the `if` statement is executed for each element of the list. Nice work, OP!

Comment: @BrianBerns Yes, your are right, i forgot about lazy evaluation of if-branch.