# recursive tuples in F#

Tags: f#

I want to take in a list of booleans and return the length and the number of truths in a tuple like this:  truesAndLength [true; false; false; true; true];; should be (5,3) I've tried a lot of methods but I don't seem to get it working this is what i've come up with:

```
let rec truesAndLength bs =
  match bs with
  | true::bs -> fst 1 + fst truesAndLength bs', snd 1 + snd truesAndLength bs
  | false::bs -> fst 1 + fst truesAndLength bs', snd 0 + snd truesAndLength bs
  | [] ->       (0,0)
```

can someone give me a nudge in the right direction?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [trues and length of bool list f#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71021649/trues-and-length-of-bool-list-f). Looks like you've got the same homework assignment. 

Comment: yes it does thank you very much